# who will set saml cookie which consists of credential info

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, idp

I was going through SAML doc. Consider applicatin1 will send login request, it will contact IDP for authentication, and the Idp authenticate the user.
Suppose i am login for the first time in that case IDP ask for user name password, and it saves username pasword and next time it will not ask for username password.

I have below doubts.

1. Since in saml different applications can login using same username password, how does IDP saves username and password, i read it stores in cookie, but cookie is resticted to one application, we cannot pass cookie between different application. How it is handled ?
2. Do we need to write code to create cookie to save username password, or saml /idp api will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

When I developed a SAML IdP the login was stored in a cookie that was resolved whenever the user came back to the IdP. e.g. User goes to SP1, gets redirected to IdP, logs in with username/password, IdP sets cookie for its own domain, redirects user to SP1. User then goes to SP2, gets redirected to IdP. IdP sees the cookie, resolves the user, session hasn't expired so loads user info from session and redirects user to SP2.

It's not how the IdP remembers a user that's the important bit (it can do that however it likes as the SP never sees a login). The important bit is what attributes the IdP sends to the SP. So the same user login can result in completely different attributes being sent to SP1 and SP2 from the same IdP login event.

At the SP, it's up to the application what it does with the attributes. It could create a JSESSIONID for example and hang the SAML assertion from the IdP on it. If the user returned within the JSESSIONID timeout the SP would just use those attributes. If the timeout had breached, the SP would redirect the user to the IdP but if the IdP cookie hadn't expired, the user would not need to login at the IdP again and the attributes would be sent to the SP silently.